# How to deal with exception during connection to hazelcast client

Tags: java, hazelcast

so I am using spring and hazelcast client to execute some task. Is there a way how to deal with with IlllegalStateException:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to connect to any address in the config! The following addresses were tried: []
        at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClusterListenerSupport.connectToCluster(ClusterListenerSupport.java:178) ~[hazelcast-client-3.8.6.jar:3.8.6]
        at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientClusterServiceImpl.start(ClientClusterServiceImpl.java:189) ~[hazelcast-client-3.8.6.jar:3.8.6]
        at com.hazelcast.client.impl.HazelcastClientInstanceImpl.start(HazelcastClientInstanceImpl.java:404) ~[hazelcast-client-3.8.6.jar:3.8.6]
        at com.hazelcast.client.HazelcastClientManager.newHazelcastClient(HazelcastClientManager.java:78) ~[hazelcast-client-3.8.6.jar:3.8.6]
        at com.hazelcast.client.HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(HazelcastClient.java:72) ~[hazelcast-client-3.8.6.jar:3.8.6]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_74]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_74]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_74]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_74]
```

in xml I have:

```
<bean id="hazelcast" class="com.hazelcast.client.HazelcastClient" factory-method="newHazelcastClient">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="com.hazelcast.client.config.ClientConfig">
            <property name="networkConfig" ref="hazelcastNetworkConfig"/>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

and in in code I am autowiring this client.

```
@Autowired
private HazelcastInstance hazelcast;
```

When there is problem with connection I can not even deploy my application. So for example when there is problem with connection instance should be null and I will use my cache or some different solution. I just don't want to throw exception when hazelcast is not avaible

```
        if (useHazelCast(...))
            useHazelcastCache(...)
        else
            useLocalCache(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a spring expert but I'd just go ahead and use my own provider which will not create the Hazelcast instance at all but return null in case of localCache = true.